# Change specific deploy site Firebase Hosting

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm using Firebase Hosting and I several webs on my app. The two firsts webs point to the same flutter app, but the third, which is a custom domain should be a different flutter web app, but when I do firebase deploy (after flutter build web) it publishes the same content for all of them. I tried to change the firebase.json of my new flutter web app to point to mydomain.com but I get this error: "manifest.json:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 "

Please, could someone guide me on how to have two different flutter web apps on the same firebase project?

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Panel]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not unique to Flutter.  The configuration will be the same for all web deployments, regardless of what you actually deploy.

What you will have to do is add another site to your project.  (Either that, or create an entirely new project. You have to decide which is best for your use case, but if your two apps don't share project data, then they probably shouldn't be the same project.)

Follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/multisites).  Go to the Firebase Hosting console, scroll to the bottom, and click this button to start:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes they do share data, one is the admin panel for my app (the web.app and the firebaseapp.com) and the mydomain.com will be the app. I already added the domain (I don't think it was with the button that you send me the photo), what I see now is what I see in the photo I posted. What should I do? Delete it from there and add it from "Firebase hosting supports multiple sites"? In the documentation that you linked they say something about RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER, where can I find the identifier of my domain.com app? Thanks!!

Comment: I can't really give you advice on what you ought to do next.  That depends on what your requirements are.  But if you have a new question, please post it separately so that it can be answered separately and hopefully also help others with the same question in the future.

Comment: I understand, thanks. Could you tell me where to find the RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER? Thanks

Comment: As I said, if you have another question, please post that separately. I've not worked with Firebase Hosting in this way so I don't know.